# Laravel Eloquent get data from multiple related table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

i have a deliveryForecast model and i have to create an eloquent to get data from multiple table based on 2 columns.

this is my delivery_forecasts table

```
Schema::create('delivery_forecasts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->enum('type',array('Quotation','Demo','Service Unit','Freebie','Back Job','Site Visit'));
        $table->string('type_id');
        $table->date('transaction_date');
        $table->time('transaction_time')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status',array('Pending','Approved','Cancelled'))->default('Pending');
        $table->boolean('queue')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

the question is can i create the eloquent in model? or how to make condition?

for example:

```
class DeliveryForecast extends Model
{
    public function documents(){
        if(DeliveryForecast->type == 'Quotation'){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Quotation','type_id','id');
        }
        if(DeliveryForecast->type == 'Demo'){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Demo','type_id','id');
        }
        if(DeliveryForecast->type == 'Service Unit'){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\ServiceUnit','type_id','id');
        }
        and so on .....
    }
}
```

i don't have idea to create the condition to eloquent and my query should be like this:

```
$delivery_forecast = DeliveryForecast::with('documents')
        ->get();
```

any idea guys? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the "polymorphic" section of the Eloquent documentation

Comment: in your scenario you need to create multiple function inside the `DeliveryForecast` model for each individual relationship.

Answer (score 3):

As @Scopey said, take a look at polymorphic relations: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

In order to implement polymorphic relationship You have to change Your migration to following:

```
    Schema::create('delivery_forecasts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->morphs('type');
        $table->date('transaction_date');
        $table->time('transaction_time')->nullable();
        $table->enum('status', ['Pending', 'Approved', 'Cancelled'])->default('Pending');
        $table->boolean('queue')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and then change `DeliveryForecast`'s method to following:

```
public function document()
{
    return $this->morphTo('type');
}
```

And that's all. But I would strongly suggest to add relationship in Your `Quotation`, `Demo` and other models:

```
public function deliveryForecasts()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\DeliveryForecast', 'type');
}
```

When querying `$forecast->document` Laravel will automatically fetch correct model for without any other conditional clauses.

Comment: thanks @Scopey and @Giedrius Kiršys, this works perfectly as i expected. last thing, is there's a way i can add another relation in polymorphic eloquent? something like this...  


`return $this->morphMany('App\DeliveryForecast', 'type')->with('customer');`  


because all of related tables in deliveryForecast like ('Quotation','Demo','Service Unit') has its own customer_id column.